# Ajuda com Task - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, asynctask

Boa tarde, gostaria da ajuda de vocês com ProgressBar e Task no javaFX.

Tenho um progressBar que ter seu valor alterado.
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
Task task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 427; i++) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                updateProgress(i, 427);
                updateMessage("Atualizando: "+i+" de "+427);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            return 427;
        }
    };
    pbStatus.setProgress(1);
    pbStatus.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    lbProgresso.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(427, new ThreadFactory() {
                @Override
                public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    return t;
                }
            });
    executor.execute(task);
```

O problema é o seguinte, o código roda sem erro nenhum, sóque chega em um certo momento que o meu ProgressBar (pbStatus) não atualiza mais... 
Fica parado em 21 / 91 de 427.

Alguém sabe oq pode ser?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido...

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
      lbProgresso.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
      pbStatus.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    }
});
```